# Are there undocumented invalid states for Android MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() and MediaPlayer.getDuration()?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-mediaplayer

I have an instance of the Androids MediaPlayer, where I try to keep track of the current state as good as possible.

As I use Xamarin (monodroid), I cannot use the wrapper, written by danielhawkes (https://gist.github.com/danielhawkes/1029568), but have to write my own. I ended up with that one:

```
namespace MyApp.UI.Droid
{
    public delegate void InternalStatusChangedEventHandler(object sender, MediaPlayerInternalStatusEventArgs e);

    public class MediaPlayerWrapper : Android.Media.MediaPlayer
    {
        public event InternalStatusChangedEventHandler InternalStatusChanged;

        private MediaPlayerStatus internalStatus;
        public MediaPlayerStatus InternalStatus {
            get { return internalStatus; }
            set {
                internalStatus = value;

                if (InternalStatusChanged != null)
                    InternalStatusChanged(this, new MediaPlayerInternalStatusEventArgs(internalStatus));
            }
        }

        public MediaPlayerWrapper() : base() {
            InternalStatus = MediaPlayerStatus.IDLE;

            Prepared += (object sender, EventArgs e) => InternalStatus = MediaPlayerStatus.PREPARED;
            Error += (object sender, ErrorEventArgs e) => InternalStatus = MediaPlayerStatus.ERROR;

            Completion += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                if (!Looping)
                    InternalStatus = MediaPlayerStatus.PLAYBACK_COMPLETED;
            };
        }

        public override void Reset ()
        {
            InternalStatus = MediaPlayerStatus.IDLE;
            base.Reset ();
        }

        public override void SetDataSource (Android.Content.Context context, Android.Net.Uri uri)
        {
            InternalStatus = MediaPlayerStatus.INITIALIZED;
            base.SetDataSource (context, uri);
        }

        public override void SetDataSource (Android.Content.Context context, Android.Net.Uri uri, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, string> headers)
        {
            InternalStatus = MediaPlayerStatus.INITIALIZED;
            base.SetDataSource (context, uri, headers);
        }

        public override void SetDataSource (Java.IO.FileDescriptor fd)
        {
            InternalStatus = MediaPlayerStatus.INITIALIZED;
            base.SetDataSource (fd);
        }

        public override void SetDataSource (Java.IO.FileDescriptor fd, long offset, long length)
        {
            InternalStatus = MediaPlayerStatus.INITIALIZED;
            base.SetDataSource (fd, offset, length);
        }

        public override void SetDataSource (string path)
        {
            InternalStatus = MediaPlayerStatus.INITIALIZED;
            base.SetDataSource (path);
        }

        public override void PrepareAsync ()
        {
            InternalStatus = MediaPlayerStatus.PREPARING;
            base.PrepareAsync ();
        }

        public override void Prepare ()
        {
            InternalStatus = MediaPlayerStatus.PREPARED;
            base.Prepare ();
        }

        public override void Start ()
        {
            InternalStatus = MediaPlayerStatus.STARTED;
            base.Start ();
        }

        public override void Pause ()
        {
            InternalStatus = MediaPlayerStatus.PAUSED;
            base.Pause ();
        }

        public override void Stop ()
        {
            InternalStatus = MediaPlayerStatus.STOPPED;
            base.Stop ();
        }

        public override void Release ()
        {
            InternalStatus = MediaPlayerStatus.END;
            base.Release ();
        }
    }

    public class MediaPlayerInternalStatusEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public MediaPlayerInternalStatusEventArgs(MediaPlayerStatus status)
        {
            this.Status = status;
        }

        public MediaPlayerStatus Status { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

After a while of testing and re-reading the docs (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#Valid_and_Invalid_States) I stumbled on one thing:

The method `MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()` is reported to be invalid to call in the `Error` state of the instance. But in my example, it also triggers the `OnError` handler, if the player is in the `Idle` state.

Same to the method `MediaPlayer.getDuration()`. It is reported to be invalid to call in the `Idle, Initialized, Error` state of the instance. But in my example, it also triggers the `OnError` handler, if the player is in the `PREPARING` state.

Is the documentation wrong here? Or am I missing something in my wrapper? Is this something special for MonoDroid maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Check instance.isPlaying() or isPaused() before a call to getCurrentPosition().

Only call getDuration() once in onPrepared() and store the value.

As mentioned in other threads, MediaPlayer state handling be a beehutch.
There is no getState() method.

Not only that, you can't add codecs to it. Also, the network streaming be dain bramaged (esp. for youtube).

It was prematurely released and like much of Android, now it be stuck with its bad self.

In my next project I will use any other extensible sensible opensource player like VLC.

Comment: That would be a work-around for MP3 files saved as `cbr` - and that's not a solution for `getCurrentPosition()` ...

Comment: Wrong. This works independently of media type. It only depends on player state.

Answer (score 0):

The `Preparing` state is not mentioned as invalid state for any of the method calls, but it's a generally unstable and undefined state to call anything in.

As stated a bit earlier in the documentation:

> It is important to note that the Preparing state is a transient state, and the behavior of calling any method with side effect while a MediaPlayer object is in the Preparing state is undefined.